# Convert pot file to array

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

So, what I need to do is to convert the contents of a `.pot` file to an array.

I know there is [`_locale_import_read_po()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21locale.inc/function/_locale_import_read_po/7.x), but when I tried using it with the following code, I got an error.

```
$translations = _locale_import_read_po('db-store', 'translations.pot');
```

The `translations.pot` file is located in the same directory containing the file with the code I wrote.

The error I get with `dpm($translations)` is the following one.

> Error message
>
> The translation import failed, because the file could not be read.

This is the code from the `_locale_import_read_po()` function, that outputs that error.

```
// The file will get closed by PHP on returning from this function.
$fd = fopen($file->uri, 'rb');
if (!$fd) {
  _locale_import_message('The translation import failed, because the file %filename could not be read.', $file);
  return FALSE;
}
```

As far as I know the `'rb'` file open mode is to open non-text files.

Why do I get that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of [`_locale_import_read_po()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21locale.inc/function/_locale_import_read_po/7.x) is a Drupal file object, which in Drupal 7 is simply a `stdClass` object.

The quicker way to use that function and pass a file object as it expects is using code similar to the following one.

```
 $po_files = file_scan_directory('./', '^translation\.po$', array('recurse' => FALSE));
 if (count($po_files)) {
   require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/locale.inc';
   $po_file = reset($po_files);
   _locale_import_read_po('db-store', $po_file);
 }
```

Notice that the second argument of [`file_scan_directory()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7.x) is a [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) regular expression, not a filename.

Using that code, you don't need to save the file using the [file API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/7.x), which is essentially useless, since there is already a file in the file system.
[`file_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save/7.x) stores the file in the database; for a file that is used for a single operation like that, it's not necessary.

I used [`st()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21install.inc/function/st/7.x) as example for writing the code I shown in this answer.

You could also make the code I show more generic to accept a regular expression and a directory name, and use it to load more files.

```
function mymodule_import_translations($directory, $pattern) {
  $po_files = file_scan_directory($directory, $pattern, array('recurse' => FALSE));
  if (count($po_files)) {
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/locale.inc';
    foreach ($po_files as $po_file) {
      _locale_import_read_po('db-store', $po_file);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$file` parameter needs to be a *Drupal file object* corresponding to the PO file to import.

You can create one using the [file_save function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save/7.x):

```
$file = file_save((object)array(
    'filename' => $file_name,
    'uri' => $destination_uri,
    'status' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($destination_uri),
  ));
```